# Problem with Reindex Data Category Products SQLSTATE[23000]

Tags: sql, reindex

After adding some products to the magento , I'm now getting this error when i try to reindex "category products" :

```
There was a problem with reindexing process. SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`domain_shop`.`catalog_category_product_index`, CONSTRAINT `catalog_category_product_index_ibfk_3` FOREIGN KEY (`product_id`) REFERENCES `catalog_product_entity` (`entity_id`) ON DELETE CAS)
```

I've searched for answers here , and I tried some queries in phpmyadmin , but none of them worked . 
Also , I don't have access to SSH of my website .   Control panel is DirectAdmin.
Any helps would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Somehow you've managed to break your database integrity. That error message is telling you that there is a value in product_id that's not in catalog_product_entity.entity_id, which makes it look like you've deleted a product, and it's didn't get deleted from catalog_category_product or catalog_category_product_index like what it's supposed to.

If that's the case then these queries will list the ids for you

```
select product_id from catalog_category_product ccp left join catalog_product_entity cpe ON product_id = entity_id where entity_id is null;
select product_id from catalog_category_product_index ccpi left join catalog_product_entity cpe ON product_id = entity_id where entity_id is null;
```

I think you'll be able to delete the rows that have those product_ids and then you'll be able to rebuild the index.

Comment: the first query returns this :
>  #1146 - Table 'bioimager_shop.catalog_category_product_ccp' doesn't exist

Comment: oh, sorry, that should have read `catalog_category_product ccp` with the space in

Comment: I've run those queries , It's still saying this :
>  There was a problem with reindexing process. SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`domain_shop`.`catalog_category_product_index`, CONSTRAINT `catalog_category_product_index_ibfk_3` FOREIGN KEY (`product_id`) REFERENCES `catalog_product_entity` (`entity_id`) ON DELETE CAS)

Comment: Yeah, I said those queries would list the ids in those tables that were violating the constraints on them, not that it would fix it. I said to fix it you'd then need to delete those rows.

Comment: I know , but those queries returns zero rows , 0 results !

Comment: Then I'd either turn on the mysql general query log to see what exact query was doing it, or have a look in `app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Resource/Category/Indexer/Product.php` at reindexAll and debug the sql from there

Answer (score -3):

Execute this query:

```
TRUNCATE `sales_flat_quote`; 
ALTER TABLE `sales_flat_quote` AUTO_INCREMENT=1; 
TRUNCATE `sales_flat_quote_address`; 
ALTER TABLE `sales_flat_quote_address` AUTO_INCREMENT=1; 
TRUNCATE `sales_flat_quote_address_item`; 
ALTER TABLE `sales_flat_quote_address_item` AUTO_INCREMENT=1; 
TRUNCATE `sales_flat_quote_item`; 
ALTER TABLE `sales_flat_quote_item` AUTO_INCREMENT=1; 
TRUNCATE `sales_flat_quote_item_option`; 
ALTER TABLE `sales_flat_quote_item_option` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
TRUNCATE `sales_flat_quote_payment`; 
ALTER TABLE `sales_flat_quote_shipping_rate` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;

TRUNCATE `log_customer`;
ALTER TABLE `log_customer` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
TRUNCATE `log_quote`;
ALTER TABLE `log_quote` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
TRUNCATE `log_summary`;
ALTER TABLE `log_summary` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
TRUNCATE `log_summary_type`;
ALTER TABLE `log_summary_type` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
TRUNCATE `log_url`;
ALTER TABLE `log_url` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
TRUNCATE `log_url_info`;
ALTER TABLE `log_url_info` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
TRUNCATE `log_visitor`;
ALTER TABLE `log_visitor` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
TRUNCATE `log_visitor_info`;
ALTER TABLE `log_visitor_info` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
TRUNCATE `report_event`;
ALTER TABLE `report_event` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
```

Then reindex again.